# vs.net first time exceptions filter

Tags: visual-studio, first-chance-exception

In visual studio you can activate break on first change exceptions. In my application I would like to ignore certain exceptions (validation and installation) and I have to disable those by hand.

Is there a way to set up the first change exception window with a set of default exceptions to catch and/or ignore?

Comment: My question is actually a duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832217/can-i-adjust-the-visual-studio-break-when-an-exception-is-thrown-options-progra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a macro, using the [ExceptionGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte90.debugger3.exceptiongroups.aspx) property.

Comment: Using a macro to changes a group of exceptions works really slow. Maybe I'm doing something wrong but togglin one exception after another in the CLR group takes over 3 minutes. IN vs.net it happens instantanious.