# Is there a keystroke in Visual Studio to toggle break on all CLR exceptions, first chance?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, exception

To toggle break on all exceptions right now, I have to:

1. Debug->Exceptions
2. Click in the `Thrown` column next to "Common Language Runtime Eceptions"
3. OK

[image]

Normally I want to stop on all exceptions, but when working in code that uses exceptions in mainline cases, I need to disable that behavior. Having a keystroke would be nice.

Comment: I suppose you could record a macro to do this and bind it to a key combo...

Comment: @JerKimball: A recorded macro contains a single line `DTE.ExecuteCommand("Debug.Exceptions")` - and will indeed only show the dialog.

Comment: It's easy to bind a key to open the dialog (and I already have such a binding, by default). But I want a key to toggle the break-on-all.

Comment: Related: [Can I adjust the visual studio "Break when an exception is thrown" options programatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/832217)

Comment: With Cody Grays hint:

    Dim debugger As Debugger3 = DTE.Debugger  
    Dim exceptionGroup As ExceptionSettings = debugger.ExceptionGroups.Item("Common Language Runtime Exceptions")  

For Each ex As ExceptionSetting In exceptionGroup
   exceptionGroup.SetBreakWhenThrown(True, ex)
Next
 
But this is terribly slow. (Sorry, don't know how to include linebreaks in a comment.)

Comment: @CodyGray: The macros system is gone from VS2012, but the automation model is still there. You can reach it from the PowerShell-based Package Manager Console (e.g. `$dte.Debugger`) but I'm not sure how to get the `ExceptionGroups` from it.

Comment: Nuts! I didn't realize this question was about VS 2012. I haven't switched yet, the UI is intolerable for me. Well, that's why I didn't vote to close as a dupe. :-)

Comment: See also this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62264331/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-enable-disable-common-language-runtime-exceptio)/[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70267307/9300908) using  Visual Commander for later versions of Visual Studio

Answer (score 6):

There is no built-in way to do this.
However, unless you are using Visual Studio Express you can try this Extension: [Exception Breaker](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/50091e25-9e75-40d3-9780-a05892f474de), it works for me.

What this extension does is provide a toolbar-button that basically toggles the checkbox you showed in your picture. And you can assign a keystroke to it like any other toolbar-button.